# Error 401 BAN Fastly

Tags: api, varnish, fastly

I am dealing with a strange issue, I have my [API platform](https://api-platform.com/) project hosted in Heroku and I am using fastly as Cache ( Varnish Cache).

My problem is that first time that I executed a PUT request, I get this error:

"hydra:description": "Client error: BAN http://example.global.ssl.fastly.net resulted in a 401 Unauthorized response:\n{"code":401,"message":"JWT Token not found"}\n",

If I try again then I don't have any error and is working correctly again.

This means that the cache servers are trying to invalidate the resource but is not able to "login".

**Important:** In my local environment is working fine.

Any ideas?